# android getRelativeTimeSpanString month is always January

Tags: java, android

the following code is returning "2 Jan" when it should be returning "2 Aug" or to be exact "moments ago":

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
long time = mDataset.get(position).Time.getTime();
String Time = (String) DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(time,now,0L,DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What values do you get for _time_ (the difference in millis from _now_)?

Answer (score 0):

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
//HERE IS THE PROBLEM => long time = mDataset.get(position).Time.getTime();
long threeSecondsAgo = System.currentTimeMillis() - 3000;
String time = (String) DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(threeSecondsAgo, now, 0L, DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL);
Log.d("time", time);
```

Log result => time﹕ 3 secs ago

What is the value of **long time**? can you debug or provide mDataset fill method?